# How to recompile exim4-daemon-heavy?

Tags: debian, openssl, exim

I have had a few problem with exim4 and various phone mail clients (Windows Phone in particular) that seem to result from bad mail clients together with GnuTLS. I'd like to recompile exim4-daemon-heavy to use OpenSSL to see if that helps anything.

Now, I've gotten used to debian's packaging system and am unsure on how to do this. I've downloaded the exim4 source using `apt-get source exim4`. I then edited the file Debian/rules to uncomment `OpenSSL = 1`.

Then I tried `make`, but was told that I need to copy the template `src/EDITME` to `Local/Makefile` and edit it to my taste. My taste would be a drop-in replacement for the existing and running exim4-daemon-heavy, just using OpenSSL. And here I am stumped as there are quite a lot of options there and I don't like to break my email setup more than neccessary.

So... what can I do to make this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the answer is in my comment/duplicate, lets do a summary of the commands you need for:

### Building exim4-daemon-heavy in Debian-like distros

```
mkdir exim4 && cd exim4
apt-get source exim4     
sudo apt-get build-dep exim4
cd exim4-4.82  ### This could be different for you
##Modify your option here in the `debian/rules` file
~/src/exim4/exim4-4.82$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc
```

This will give you the .deb files in the parent folder. The `build-dep` action to `apt-get` installs the BUILD DEPendencies for the given package.

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely, and it even solved my TLS problems. This is a good day. =)